# Logic: If $\frac{1}{x} > 0.5$, then $x$ can be any real number smaller than $2$?

Tags: logic

My friends are arguing whether the following statement is correct or not. It seems easy enough but I cannot tell who's argument is correct.

> If $\frac{1}{x} > 0.5$, then $x$ can be any real number smaller than $2$.

We all agree that the range of $x$ should be found as follows.
$$\frac{1}{x} > 0.5$$
$$x^2 \times \frac{1}{x} > x^2 \times 0.5$$
$$0>0.5x^2 - x$$
$$0<x<2$$

However, they have a different conclusion afterwards.

Argument $1$:

> The range is suggesting that $x$ cannot be negative. Hence, the word 'any real numer' is wrong
> . The statement is therefore
> false.

Argument $2$:

> In order for the 'if' statement to be true, we let $f(x) = \frac1x$
> and we can already ignore the case in which $x$ is negative and assume that the domain is the set of all positive real numbers. In this domain,
> all numbers must be smaller than $2$ for $f(x)$ to be smaller than
> $2$. Hence, the statement is true.

Can you share your view on this? Is the statement true or false? Thank you.

Comment: Anyway that sentence is not well-phrased. "$x$ can be..." is weird. If you write rigorously your sentence, its truth-status (which will depend on what you write) will be doubtless.

Comment: The statement is not true. Even though you can deduce the positivity of $x$ from the assumption, you cannot omit in the conclusion. Such an affirmation would imply: if $x>0$ then $x$ can be $-1$.

Comment: The claim can be reformulated (assuming that $x$ is a real number, but what should it be else ? In the complex numbers we have no order) , namely that for every real $x<2$ , we have $\frac{1}{x}>0.5$ (The vacous truth does not apply here). And this is clearly false , since $x$ can neither be negative nor $0$.

Comment: @Peter : May I ask if I have interpreted your comment correctly? My statement is $P \rightarrow Q$, but your reformulation is $Q \rightarrow P$.

Comment: That $x$ can be any real number smaller than $2$ means that I can take such a real number smaller than $2$ (OK, $0$ should be ruled out) and that this inequality holds then. I did not interprete it as an implication in the sense you mentioned. The way the claim is stated is anyway confusing as Anne also pointed out.

Comment: In the given interpretation of an implication, the statement is wrong as well : Say $x=1$ , then the premise is true. But then, $x$ cannot be any real number smaller than $2$.

Comment: "... we can already ignore the case in which $x$ is negative and assume that the domain is the set of all positive real numbers." What is the justification for this? Anyways, the domain should be defined as part of the question: the answerer shouldn't be left guessing what the domain was...

Answer (score 2):

The statement to (dis)prove is of the form: "If A , Then B."

Since in your case, statement A is *equivalent* to the result $0 < x < 2$, we can rewrite it as:

"If $\:0<x<2$, Then $x$ can be any real number smaller than 2", which is clearly **false**, as $x$ cannot be, for example, $-1$.

In a case like this, for the original statement to be true, we want the solutions to statement B to be a *subset or equal* to the solutions to statement A, rather than a superset.

For example, a statement that would work would be: "If $\frac{1}{x} < 0.5$, Then $0<x<2$"

Answer (score 0):

> My friends are arguing whether the following statement is correct or not.
>
> > If $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol x} > 0.5,$ then $\boldsymbol x$ can be any real number smaller than $2.$

Unless $x$ symbolises a constant—in which case the statement is false because $x$ is not *any* but some (in fact, a particular) real number smaller than $2$—the quoted line is **not even a statement**, due to $x$ being a free variable.

On the other hand, this is a false statement:

- for each $\boldsymbol x,$ if $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol x} > 0.5$, then $\boldsymbol x$ can be any real number smaller than $2.$

And these are true statements:

- for some $\boldsymbol x,$ if $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol x} > 0.5$, then $\boldsymbol x$ can be any real number smaller than $2$
- for each $\boldsymbol x,$ if $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol x} > 0.5$, then $\boldsymbol x$ is a real number smaller than $2.$

> Argument $1$:
>
> > The range is suggesting that $x$ cannot be negative. Hence, the word 'any real number' is wrong
> > . The statement is therefore false.

No:

- if $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol x} > 0.5,$ then $\boldsymbol x$ can be any real number *strictly between $0$ and $2$*

is **still** not a statement, while

- for each $\boldsymbol x,$ if $\frac{1}{\boldsymbol x} > 0.5$, then $\boldsymbol x$ can be any real number *strictly between $0$ and $2$*

is **still** a false statement.

> Argument $2$:
>
> > In order for the 'if' statement to be true, we let $f(x) = \frac1x$
> > and we can already ignore the case in which $x$ is negative and assume that the domain is the set of all positive real numbers. In
> > this domain,
> > all numbers must be smaller than $2$ for $f(x)$ to be smaller than
> > $2$. Hence, the statement is true.

No, if we restrict the domain of discourse to positive numbers and treat the quoted line as an implicitly universally quantified statement, then the statement is **false**, because each instantiation of $x$ (i.e., ‘for each $x\text’)$ is still a single real number rather than *any* real number.

On a separate note: given a number $c$ such that $0<c<2,$ surely you agree that it is **perfectly correct** to assert that $c<2$ ? After all, we are claiming merely that the former inequality implies the latter inequality, not that they are equivalent to each other.